# Is it possible to take the mean of hourly data to get a daily data

Tags: time-series

I would like to work with hourly recorded data. I would like to convert it to daily data. I am thinking of taking the mean of each day. However, I am not sure if this is correct or no?

Any help, please?

Comment: Yes you can do that. However, in aggregating the data you may lose some important patterns, this may or may not be important for your task.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the sum of what happens in each 1-hour period that gives you the daily value?

Comment: @Dave Or sorry, I think I should take the sum of the day to give me the value of the day.

Comment: @Mary I really have no idea what alternative you have to adding up the hourly values to find the daily values. It would be like finding your restaurant bill a way other than adding up the prices of each dish (okay, there's tax and tip, but you get the idea). Do you have another idea in mind?

Comment: @Dave Thank you so much for your nice and helpful comments. In statistic, we usually take the mean of the hourly data to get the daily value. I even remember (a long time ago) my supervisor said that to me. But I never work with such data before.

Comment: @Mary That gets you the average amount per hour during that day, which is a quantity you might find interesting or useful. However, it's not the amount from that day. I'd be very skeptical of my memory of what the supervisor said. Imagine doing this when it's time to pay the restaurant bill. "Expensive steak, \$46. Coke, \$2. I'll average them and pay \$24."

Answer (score 1):

You can build a model at the hourly level and forecast the next N hours for the next K days

If there are hidden/latent anthropormorphic effects such as day-of-the-week effects , day-of-the-month effects they may be detectable. If there are deterministically significant seasonal effects i.e.monthly effects they may be detectable and used with assumptions. If there are level shifts or local  time trends or anomalies they may be detectable.

Only your data knows for sure. You might search on SE https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3382+hourly for more discussions about hourly data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, my data is for one year. For example, air pollution (recorded hourly) for the year 2018!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, calling it as a smoothing (moving average) process (please, don't confuse this meaning of moving average with the one related, for example, to ARMA process).

It worth noting that if you have 240 hourly data, this process give you only 10 daily data points. Are they enought? Good. If not, there is another way.
Depending on your task, you could preserve the initial number of observation in your sample by using a *rolling window* to average:

- take the mean of the first 24 observations (1st to 24th), which is the first daily data point;
- take the mean of the "second" 24 observations (not from 25th to 48th, but from the 2nd to 25th) to obtain the second data point;
- and so on...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I really do not get the second point. Why do you think, for the second 24 observations, I should start from the $2^{nd}$ observation instead of the $25^{th}$?

Comment: Dear @Mary, from 1 pm of today to 1pm of Tomorrow there is one day. But also from 2 pm of today to 2 pm of Tomorrow there are 24 hours, one day. The same for 3 pm or 7 am and so on.

If your is the case (and I don't know if it is!), you could obtain daily observation in this way. Make sense?

Comment: @Mary, by the way, since you have one year of hourly data (a large sample, even if I don't know what is your goal!), I think you can simply average each 24 data, as told you@IrishStat, obtaining however a sample big enough to, for example, forecasting few days ahed your last observation. But I have to undestand your goal to better advise you!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Apologise for the delay. My data is air pollution. I would like to fit a regression model to this data.